# share the same vbox virtual machine between different host platforms?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I can only test my own cross-platform projects on a real machine, because their performance is very critical. Thus I had several different host OSs (linux, winxp, win7...) installed on the same PC for testing.

I am always developing all the projects in a guest environment with the VirtualBox. I would also prefer to be able to see the performance changes according to my modification to the source codes. Thus I would like to have the exactly same developing environment for all the different host OSs.

At present, I keep 1 virtual machine for each different host OS. And I was using share folder to store projects files, that is OK under most circumstances. However, if I wanna do a system update, package installation, etc, I have to repeat the same process for all virtual machines on all the hosts. This became very annoying since I did this very often recently.

Is that possible to reuse the virtualbox *.vdi, config XML files in different hosts? If it is possible, I might be able to ONLY keep one set of vdi files for the guests in all the different hosts?

I knew the most expensive and easiest alternative is to buy another machine for development, but this is not an option to me.

Does anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 1):

Wang, to answer your questions, with some qualifications:

Yes, It is possible to re-use your VirtualBox hard-disk files and config files on different hosts.

Yes, I have experience and have done it.

Notes:

- How you do it (you didn't ask) is somewhat up to you, as what you want to do is not officially supported by virtualbox.

  - How well it works may depend on your host and guest OS, and whether you intend to make use of snapshots and/or saved state.
  - Whether or not you can directly use the config files may depend on how your paths are set up, and if you are using version 4 .vbox config files or the older .xml config files.
  - How your guest OS will respond to running on different virtual hardware (cpuid, for example) may depend on the OS.
- For further information, I suggest you search the virtualbox forum.
- Your question may have been better asked on SuperUser, not StackOverflow.